# How do I start the mission packs on Watch Dogs?

Tags: watch-dogs

After finishing Watch Dogs, I decided to buy the Season Pass as it comes with the bonus mission packs that came as preorder bonuses.

However, when I loaded the game, there was no prompt for new missions and I can't see any new icons on the map.

Is this a known issue with the Season Pass, or something I'm overlooking?

How do I start the Breakthrough Pack, Signature Shot Pack, and the Palace Pack missions?

Here's some more info, in the event that this is a bug/issue:

- I'm on Xbox One.
- I've finished the game, currently in the post-game.
- I've checked that the season pass is showing up under additional content.
- I've received the Club outfit from the Season Pass, but none of the missions are showing (as far as I can see).

Comment: This "bug" is happening to me aswell on the pc though i got conspricay and the mobster pack but no exclusive missions i restarted the game once to see if that is the problem i am currently on act II not sure what the prob is..

Comment: The Conspiracy Pack can be accessed through digital trips, by the way.

Comment: I'd like to provide a full answer, but I can't because it's locked by Community.  I had a similar problem (accessing DLC content after buying and downloading the Season Pass).  You have to additionally download and install the DLC (installing the season pass, just makes the DLC free in the store).  To download the DLC, load the game and go to the appropriate menu, which will link you to the store.  When the DLC has an "Install" button rather than a button with a price, that's when you know it's free and ready to install.

Comment: How do you play co-op and the exclusive "T-Bone" missions though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to play the campaign to a certain point (as far as I know it's till Act II) and then you will recognize new *GPS points* on your map that say **exclusive mission**. Just drive there and start it, and after finishing them you will recieve the bonus (e.g. more battery)! Good luck *:)*

Comment: I've finished the game, so that shouldn't be an issue. Any pointers on what the icons look like?

Comment: They are of a different blue, and with a symbol representing the network of ctOS.

Comment: @DrakaSAN I'm starting to think this may be a bug - there's nothing matching your description on the map, unless I'm missing something obvious here. I've edited some more information into the question in case this helps.

Comment: [This](http://www.primagames.com/dims3/PRIMA/http://www.primagames.com/media/files/ctrl_location.jpg) probably is the exclusive contract icon you're referring to.

Comment: @BiscuitBaker [CaP0Ne](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/77019/cap0ne) linked the Image I was also looking for. Can you find any of these? Have you activated the DLC's ingame in the main menu?

Comment: Im on PS4. I am searching the web too, to find out how to access season pass. I dl'd it, I guess Ill be back to ask again. Gonna look for those icons you said that would be on the map, what do they look like exactly?